# Persistence of user input after reboot

Tags: power, arduino-due, eeprom

I am creating an application where user input is required. After a user browses through available choices (via buttons and LCD) depending on the choice of the user a function is run from several available.

When the user reboots the Arduino, it starts from the default function, making the user reselect the choice they want..

Is there a way to have persistence of the choice of the user after a reboot?
So that, when a user makes a selection, after a reboot, the arduino will have this selection (=the function that corresponds to this selection) by default.

Maybe if the user input (the buttons) write to an EEPROM or something like this? So that the arduino reads the value from the component?

If such a solution exists, due to limitations i would like to have only one wire for communication with the device.

EDIT: I am using Arduino Due

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better than that: Zero wires.

The Arduino has EEPROM built in.

Comment: I forgot to mention i am using Arduino Due

Comment: The Arduino due has flash memory based EEPROM emulation built in.

Comment: I searched for it... Do you mean this: https://github.com/sebnil/DueFlashStorage

Comment: Ok, maybe the due doesn't have it as default (lazy buggers, all the other larger boards do), but yes that looks like it should plug the gaping hole Arduino left in the due.